# excel macro to search for specific string

Tags: vba, excel

i need to write and excel macro to search for a string and replace it with another... how do i do this ?
HELP :/

Comment: I think you need to specify more information. Where do you need to search for the string? Do you already have some code or do you need guidance in getting started?

Answer (score 2):

You can record that operations, and Alt+Shift+F11 to open the Script Editor, then reference the code generated by the Recorder. I think that can give you some hints.

And I think you don't need to use Macro. It is enough to use the "Find and Replace" Menu Item, and choose the option you want.

Comment: it is giving me absolute code for the each cell not a code extensible to the whole worksheet.

Comment: also i need to search each row and replace values with in each cell, eg. 1-abc   344-abc   455-abc are different cells but i need to replace abc, excel doesnt have the search and replace function fro this. atleast not in office 2007

Answer (score 2):

Using **user interface** in Excel 2007

1. Select cell A1
2. Click on the Home tab in the Ribbon
3. Click on the 'Find & Select' icon and select 'Replace'
4. Click on the 'Options' button
5. Enter the text to search for 'abc' in the 'Find What' box
6. Enter the text to replace 'abc' with in the 'Replace with' box
7. Make sure that the tick boxes are not ticked
8. Make sure Within = Sheet, Search = By Rows and Look in = Formulas
9. Click on the 'Replace all' button

[image: Replace screenshot]

---

Using **VBA** code

```
Sub Replace_abc()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Replace What:="abc", Replacement:="def", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```